# Can't connect to IBus error

Tags: ibus, i3-wm

I'm trying to type Vietnamese in Ubuntu 20.04 with `i3wm` (with `GNOME` everything works fine) but I'm getting an error: "Can't connect to Ibus" when execute the following command:

```
ibus list-engine
```

I'm currently using `i3wm` version 4.7.1 and `ibus` version 1.5.22. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After executing this command, I can use `ibus` again. I don't understand why :(( Thank god.

```
ibus-daemon --xim -d -r
```